# Bad stereo mapping in RTABmap

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap, rtab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a stereo camera, Intel T265 and I am getting strange stereo map:

[image: image description]

Why is that?
I have also recorded the bag:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sjh1QdhBczf9v69mqZckdFTdfV8486nl/view?usp=sharing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318700/bad-stereo-mapping-in-rtabmap/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rtabmap requires **rectified** stereo images as input. There are a lot of right images missing from the bag, but I'm still able to try [stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc) to rectify the images:

```
$ rosrun stereo_image_proc stereo_image_proc /left/image_raw:=/camera/fisheye1/image_raw /left/camera_info:=/camera/fisheye1/camera_info /right/image_raw:=/camera/fisheye2/image_raw /right/camera_info:=/camera/fisheye2/camera_info
```

Raw:

[image: image description]

Rectified:

[image: image description]

As you can see, the rectification doesn't work with the current calibration info. Here is a tutorial to calibrate stereo cameras: http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-03-23**:
@matlabbe Hi thank you, I already figured this out but gave up on a camera for a while as calibrating was not perfect. Meanwhile, can you have a look at my new question?
https://answers.ros.org/question/319313/why-does-pointcloud-pointing-upwards/